# Find limit $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \, \frac{\arctan(3x)}{\tan\big((x+3\pi)/3\big)}$ without using L'Hospital's rule

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Can anybody help me find this limit without using L'Hospital's rule?
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \, \frac{\arctan(3x)}{\tan\big((x+3\pi)/3\big)}$$
I've tried to multiply both $\arctan/\tan$ on $\sin$, but it doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following facts.

- $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\arctan(3x)}{\tan((x+3\pi)/3)} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\arctan(3x)}{3x} \times \frac{3x}{\tan\frac{x+3\pi}{3}}$
- $\displaystyle\tan\left(\pi +\frac{x}{3}\right) = \tan\left(\frac{x}{3}\right)$

Answer (score 1):

We have

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\arctan(3x)}{\tan ((x+3\pi)/3)}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\arctan(3x)}{\tan (x/3)}=\lim_{x\to0}3\frac{x/3}{\tan (x/3)}\frac{\arctan (3x)}{x}\\=9\arctan'(0)=\frac9{1+0^2}=9$$

Answer (score 0):

Since 
$$\operatorname{tg}{\frac{x+3\pi}{3}}=\operatorname{tg}{\left(\frac{x}{3}+\pi\right)}=\operatorname{tg}{\left(\frac{x}{3}\right)} \underset{x\to{0}}\sim \frac{x}{3},\\
\operatorname{arctg}{(3x)}\underset{x\to{0}}\sim 3x,$$
then
$$\dfrac{\operatorname{arctg}{(3x)}}{\operatorname{tg}{\frac{x+3\pi}{3}}}\underset{x\to{0}}\to 9.$$